# How to frame \part in an article?

Tags: parts

I would like to frame the content of \part.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{Cours}
\section{test part}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you have a fancy way to frame it ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Clarification question: do you want to draw a frame around the word _Cours_, or around the words _Première partie_, or one frame around both, or a frame around everything in the part up to the next part (so including the section title and text below, i.e., the whole page until the following `\part` command)?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to add a fancy frame is by using the `tcolorbox` package.

The size of the box will adjust to its content. It's pretty easy to change colors, text alignment, and other properties.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% ***************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

   \newtcbox{\partbox}[1][]{%
    colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black, % colors <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    tikznode= {align =left}, % text align <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    nobeforeafter,
    tcbox raise base}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright%
        \interlinepenalty \@M%
        \normalfont
        \partbox{\Large\bfseries \partname~\thepart \\[1ex] \huge \bfseries #2}     
        \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak\vskip 3ex\@afterheading}

\def\@spart#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \partbox{\huge \bfseries #1}\par}%
    \nobreak\vskip 3ex  \@afterheading}
\makeatother
% *****************************************

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \part{Cours}
    \section{test part}
    
    \part{Nouveau matériel}
    
\part*{La fin}
    
\end{document}
```

You can get a vanilla style using

```
\newtcbox{\partbox}[1][]{% vanilla style
    colback=white, colframe= black,
    sharp corners,
    tikznode= {align =left}, % text align <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    nobeforeafter,  tcbox raise base }
```

[image: c]

**Option**

Instead of modifying `\@part` you can define a new command `\fpart` and use e.g. as `\fpart{Cours}`

```
\newcommand{\fpart}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \noindent\partbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries \partname~\thepart \\[1ex] \huge \bfseries #1} 
    \markboth{}{}%
}
```

Comment: Maybe good to mention that you can use this approach as well if you want a non-fancy frame, i.e., black line, no fill color, non-rounded corners, by changing the relevant `tcbox` options.

Comment: Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Hello it's me again. 
I have a new problem : my part title is too long to fit in one line.
How can the command be modified to write this title in 2 or more lines ?